# Solving in One Line

Tags: python-3.x

The question goes. Strange communication has been intercepted between two alien species at war. NASAs top inguists have determined that these aliens use a weird numbering system. They have symbols for various numeric values, and they just add all the values for the symbols in a given numeral to calculate the number. NASA's linguists have given you the following table of symbols and their numeric values. Since they have a lot of these numbers to compute, they want you to write a function that they can use to automate this task. Value 1024 598 121 42 Sym Thus a!ya!U!NaU represents a value of 1095 (see table below for an explanation) Numeral Value OccurrencesTotal ValueRunning Total 1024 598 121 42 0 x 10240 1 × 598 598 3 x 121363 3 x 42 = 126 598 961 1087 1093 1095 alienNumbers that takes one string parameter s, and returns the integer value represented by rite a function s. Since aliens only know these characters you may assume that no character in s outside of this set: (T,y, !,a, N, U Callenge: try to make the whole body of this function only one line long >>>alienNumbers ("a!ya!U!NaU") 1095 >>> alienNumbers ("aaaUUU") 129

Ive solved it, as shown below

```py
def alienNumbers(s):

    final = []
    new_final = []

    T_count = 0
    y_count = 0
    count = 0
    a_count = 0
    N_count = 0
    U_count = 0

    for i in s:

        final.append(i)

    for k in final:

        if k == "T":

            T_count += 1

        if k == "y":

            y_count += 1

        if k == "!":

            count += 1

        if k == "a":

            a_count += 1

        if k == "N":

            N_count += 1

        if k == "U":

            U_count += 1

    for j in final:

        if j not in new_final:

            new_final.append(j)

    for m in new_final:

        if m == "T":

            value1 = 1024 * T_count

        if m == "y":

            value2 = 598 * y_count

        if m == "!":

            value3 = 121 * count

        if m == "a":

            value4 = 42 * a_count

        if m == "N":

            value5 = 6 * N_count

        if m == "U":

            value6 = 1 * U_count

    total = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value6

    print(total)
```

But apparently this question can be solved in exactly one line of code using the .count() function in python, and I cant seem to figure it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of values by mapping characters to a dict that the keys are the characters and the values are their coded value, then sum it all up using `sum`:

```
def alienNumbers(s): print(sum(map(lambda x: {"T" : 1024, "y" : 598, "!" : 121, "a" : 42, "N" : 6, "U" : 1}[x], list(s))))
```

This will work assuming there is no characters outside `T,y, !,a, N, U`. I assumed that in your question you added the `(` character as a typo.

**EDIT**

Forgot to add that if you wanted to accept any characters and only count those inside the vocabulary, you can change that function to:

```
def alienNumbers(s): print(sum(map(lambda x: {"T" : 1024, "y" : 598, "!" : 121, "a" : 42, "N" : 6, "U" : 1}.get(x, 0), list(s))))
```

Using `dict.get` with a 0 as default value will not throw `KeyError` and will not change the total sum amount.